# SQL Group by query to select the data from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table have following data,

```
ID name  devID
1  abc    101
2  def    111
3  ghi    121
4  abc    102
5  def    110
```

I want to select the rows (ID,name,devID)based on the following condition:

a. the value of devID for name abc have been increased by 1, so only higher value record should be displayed in the result (only 102)

b. the value of devID for name def have been decrease by 1, it should display all records
(111 and 110)

Also we will be keep on adding the records for different rows and each name will not have more than 2 or max 3 rows in the table, so above condition should be always true.

Please help me on this query.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 RDBMS

Comment: Based on your data would `ghi` appear in the final result?

Comment: So your algorithm is that, based on the last devID, (if it is larger or smaller) than the previoud dev IDs, you want to affect what is returned. Can you explain better yet why you want to do all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should help you solve your problem if I have understood correctly your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_data AS a
WHERE a.devid >=
    (SELECT DEVID
     FROM table_data AS C
     WHERE c.ID =
         (SELECT max(b.ID)
          FROM table_data AS b
          GROUP BY b.name HAVING b.name = a.name)) ;
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b14513/18

This code causes only rows with a `DEVID` greater (or equal) with the last inserted `DEVID` of someone with the name `Name` to be displayed.

**Results**

```
ID  NAME    DEVID
2   def     111
3   ghi     121
4   abc     102
5   def     110
```

**Update** (Query can be simplified further to):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_data AS a
WHERE a.devid >=
    (SELECT DEVID
     FROM table_data AS C
     WHERE c.ID =
         (SELECT max(b.ID)
          FROM table_data AS b
          where b.name = a.name)) ;
```

Also indexes should be placed in ID and devID.

Answer (score 2):

I used an incremental approach. I didn't really see another option. This returns what you need I believe:

```
create table #t1
(
    ID int identity,
    name varchar(3),
    devID int
)

insert into #t1(name,devID)
values('abc',101),('def',111),('ghi',121),('abc',102),('def',110)


create table #t2
(
    ID int,
    name varchar(3),
    devID int
)

declare @count int = 1,
    @name1 varchar(3)
while @count <= (select MAX(ID) from #t1)
begin--1
    set @name1 = (select name from #t1 where ID = @count)
    if (@name1 not in (select distinct name from #t2)) or ((select devID from #t1 where ID = @count) < (select devID from #t2 where name = @name1))
    begin--2
        insert into #t2
            select *
            from #t1
            where ID = @count
    end--2
    else
    begin--2
        update #t2
            set devID = (select devID from #t1 where ID = @count)
            where name = @name1
    end--2

    set @count+=1
end--1

select *
from #t2

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```

EDIT: Results:

```
ID          name devID
----------- ---- -----------
1           abc  102
2           def  111
3           ghi  121
5           def  110

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an `INNER JOIN` with itself and `UNION` the results could be a good approach.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3903/1)

```
/* select all rows that match criteria A */
SELECT d2.ID, d2.name, d2.devID
FROM   data d1
       INNER JOIN data d2 ON d2.devID = d1.devID + 1 
                             AND d2.ID > d1.ID
UNION
/* select first rows that match criteria B */
SELECT d1.ID, d1.name, d1.devID
FROM   data d1
       INNER JOIN data d2 ON d2.devID = d1.devID - 1 
                             AND d2.ID > d1.ID
UNION
/* select second rows that match criteria B */
SELECT d2.ID, d2.name, d2.devID
FROM   data d1
       INNER JOIN data d2 ON d2.devID = d1.devID - 1 
                             AND d2.ID > d1.ID
```

Comment: your solution works but you filter out the entry for name 'GHI' which causes one missing row. See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b14513/20

Comment: +1 though for speedy results. Your query works much faster than using nested queries.

Comment: @meewoK - I know but it's not clear if it should be in the results or not *(see bluefeet's comment)*.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you simply want to get the **latest** devID (as shown below).

So **why bother with Joins and stuff**, if this simple approach works too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Name), (SELECT TOP 1 devID FROM Table t2 
WHERE t2.Name=t1.Name Order By ID desc) FROM table t1
```

Your records:

```
ID name  devID
1  abc    101
2  def    111
3  ghi    121
4  abc    102
5  def    110
```

Your expected Result (Also checked with fiddler)

```
name  devID
ghi    121
abc    102
def    110
```